# Masking an image's real URL in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I'm creating an incredibly basic photo sharing app in Rails that displays albums from the local filesystem.

For example -

```
/path/to/pictures
  |
  |-> 2003_college_graduation
  |-> 2002_miami_spring_break
```

However, anyone can take a look at the HTML source and get the absolute path to the image -

```
my.server.com/path/to/pictures/2003_college_graduation/IMG_0001.JPG
```

And with a little guesswork, anyone could navigate to other images on the server, even ones they don't have permission to.

Is there any way to "mask" the URL here?

One potential solution is to hash each filepath into a UUID and store the mappings in mysql table. Then when they request the URL with that hash I can look it up in the table and pull the correct image. But that makes the URL looks messy and creates a problem if the URL ever changes (because the hash will change).

Are there any libraries or other workarounds to mask the real path to a file?

Thanks!

Comment: Google's cache would probably give you this anyway. But you would store the images outside the (web) root folder, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a url minifier (take your pick) and use that link. They'd still be able to see the original source if they followed it, but it would get it out of the html file.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve here is a security through obscurity, which isn't going to work in the end. One can get aware of the scrambled URLs from any other source and still have access to the pics he should not be seeing.

The real solution is to actually control access to the files. It is a pretty common problem with a pretty common solution. In order to force access control you have to invoke a Rails controller action before serving the file and verify the credentials, and then, if the credentials are valid, serve the actual file.

It could be like this in the controller:

```
class PhotoController < ApplicationController
  def photo
    if user_has_access?(params[:album], params[:photo])
      # be *very* careful here to ensure that user_has_access? really validates
      # album and photo access, otherwise, there's a chance of you letting a malicious
      # user to get any file from your system by feeding in certain params[:album]
      # and params[:photo]
      send_file(File.join('/path/to/albums', params[:album], "#{params[:photo]}.jpg"), type: 'image/jpeg', disposition: 'inline')
    else
      render(file: File.join(Rails.root, 'public/403.html'), status: 403, layout: false)
    end
  end

  private

  def user_has_access?(album, photo)
    # validate that the current user has access and return true, if he does,
    # and false if not
  end
end
```

And then in your routes file:

```
get '/photos/:album/:photo.jpg' => 'photo#photo', as: album_photo
```

And then in your views:

```
<%= image_tag album_photo_path('album', 'photo') %>
```

What's good about `send_file` is that it simply serves the file out of Rails in development mode, but in production it can be configured to offload it to the actual webserver to keep the performance of your Rails code optimal.

Hope that gives a basic idea of what it might be and helps a bit!